# Show $\langle u,v\rangle \neq \mathbb{R}^2 \Leftrightarrow \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}(u = \lambda v)$

Tags: vector-spaces

$u,v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are different from $(0,0)$

I have to show that

$\langle u,v\rangle \neq \mathbb{R}^2 \Leftrightarrow \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}(u = \lambda v)$

I am not sure how to start with that exercise.

- I know that each vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a linear combination of $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$
- I need to show each direction of the arrow.

Any hints how to start?

Comment: What you wrote on the left hand side of the equivalence makes no sense. Rather than saturating the question with symbols, say in words what you need to show.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: I suspect that $\langle u,v \rangle$ means the linear span of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: What do you know about dimension and linear independence?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo:  I too took $\langle u, v \rangle = \text{span} \{u, v \}$

Comment: $\langle X \rangle$ is a set of all linear combination of vectors in X. As an example: $\langle \{(0,1),(1,0)\} \rangle = \mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\langle u, v \rangle \ne \Bbb R^2$ then $\dim \langle u, v \rangle < 2$, so we must have $\dim \langle u, v \rangle = 0 \; \text{or} \; 1$.  We rule out $0$ since $u \ne 0 \ne v$.  $\dim \langle u, v \rangle = 1$ implies there is a $w \in \langle u, v \rangle$, $w \ne 0$, with $\langle w \rangle = \langle u, v \rangle$; then there are nonzero $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R$ with $u = \alpha w$ and $v = \beta w$.  Thus $u = (\alpha / \beta) v$; set $\lambda = (\alpha / \beta)$.  To go the other way, if $u = \lambda v$ then $\alpha u + \beta v = \alpha \lambda v + \beta v = (\alpha \lambda + \beta)v$, showing that $\dim \langle u, v \rangle = 1$, so we cannot have $\langle u, v \rangle = \Bbb R^2$.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: My pleasure; glad to help out!  And thanks for the "acceptance"!